# 3 dependent choices fields in Symfony forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to achieve to have symfony (2.6) form with 3 choices fields (select) dependent on each other. All of them are just plain array choices, not entity field types.

Let's say I have this situation:

1st field has options:

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
```

2nd field is populated according to what is selected in 1st one and can have one of these options:

```
Today
Tomorrow
Never
```

(for example for "Option A" I will have "Today" and "Tomorrow", for "Option B" only "Never" etc, but I can have same choices for different options from 1st field)

and then 3rd field has some other options dependent on both 1st and 2nd field (and again, some choices can be set for different 1st + 2nd combinations).

I was going on according to this article in Symfony Cookbook -
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data - which is almost the same thing I want to achieve, but I don't have entities and I need 3rd field.

I had something like this

```
<?php
...

$builder
    ->add(
        'first_field',
        'choice',
        [
            'choices' => [some choices],
            'placeholder' => 'Choose!',
        ]
    );

$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $firstFieldValue) {
    $choices = $firstFieldValue ? $this->getChoices($firstFieldValue) : [];

    $form->add(
        'second_field',
        'choice',
        [
            'choices' => $choices,
            'disabled' => empty($choices),
        ]
    );

    ... here would be "third_field" ...
};

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        /** @var FormData $data */
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $formModifier($form, $data->getProductId());
    }
);

$builder->get('first_field')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $firstFieldValue = $event->getForm()->getData();

        $formModifier($productIdForm->getParent(), $firstFieldValue);
    }
);

$builder->get('second_field')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $secondFieldValue = $event->getForm()->getData();

        // ---------------------------------------------
        // My problem is that I need "firstFieldValue"
        // here as well, because I need to generate
        // choices according to 1st and 2nd field values
        // ---------------------------------------------
        $formModifier($productIdForm->getParent(), $secondFieldValue);
    }
);
```

And another problem was that I couldn't attach event listener on **second_field**, because I don't have it, it's added in those listeners (but probably I can add it directly in $builder->add..., but I still couldn't get **first_field** value from **second_field** listener.

Maybe someone has this specific thing implemented somewhere and can share his code? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the listeners to the parent form and get children data in the callable :

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $firstFieldValue = $form()->get('first_field')->getData();
        if ('something' === $firstFieldValue) {
            $formModifier($form, $firstFieldValue);
        } else {
            $form->remove('second_field');
            // or
            $form->get('second_field')->setData(null);
        }
    }
);

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $secondFieldValue = $event->getForm()->get('second_field')->getData();
        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $secondFieldValue);
    }
);
```

Comment: problem here is, that in POST_SUBMIT I can't add children anymore so $formModifier function will fail and in PRE_SUBMIT field's date are not yet set

Comment: Updated. Yes `PRE_SUBMIT` event holds sent string data, it may be enough to handle your stuff.

Comment: Great, it works now partially :) but let's say I have all 3 choices populated (which means I chose something in 1st field and something in 2nd field), and now I change 1st field again, then it submits all 3 fields, but I need to clear 2nd and 3rd field, because 1st field changed (but I don't know which field changed)

Comment: oh, to be honest, I don't really remember now :( but it definitely helped me a lot to get to the solution (I don't have access to that code anymore, sorry), so I will accept this as correct answer